# Solutions for orphan rate in Casper PoS?

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper, uncle-blocks

What are some possible solutions to deal with the increased orphan rate when Ethereum shifts to its Proof-of-Stake system, Casper?

Comment: Why would ophan rate inscrease with PoS ?
In PoS the validator of a block is picked at random

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that Casper will cause an increase in the number of blocks that are orphaned - and on top of that, I don't think Ethereum even really has a concept of orphaned blocks.

Because the Ethereum consensus algorithm uses a modified version of the [GHOST protocol](https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/what-is-the-ghost-protocol-for-ethereum/) and, as a result, valid blocks are included in the chain (albeit indirectly) even if they aren't in line with of the main chain.

In PoS, I have a feeling this uncle rate would actually fall, because instead of all miners working on a block at once (and therefore possibly coming to different finalized blocks at the same time - causing uncles), validators will be stochastically chosen to create blocks during specific time intervals (leading to much less overlap).